# how can I make bubbling event in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make bubbling event for clicked buttons as differently using if boolean for the buttons but i dont know how to identify the buttons to retrieve different events .. it didn't work with textContent and include()

```js
const $storybox = document.getElementById('storybox')
const $main = document.querySelector('main')
const $newHeading = document.querySelector('h2');
const $buttons = []
//get stroy frist
document.body.onload = loadPage;

function loadPage() {
  $newHeading.textContent = 'Choose a story'
  for (const title of stories) {

    $buttons.push(`<button data-story="${title['title']}"class="button">${title['title']}</button>`)

    // const list =`${$buttons.join(' ')}`
    $storybox.innerHTML = `<button data-story="${title['title']}"class="button">${title['title']}</button>` + $storybox.innerHTML
  }
  console.log($buttons)
  // $storybox.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin",$newHeading)
}

$storybox.addEventListener('click', function() {

  $storybox.classList.add('hidden')
  $newHeading.textContent = 'Provide the following words';
  if ($buttons.includes("Weather Report")) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      // for(const word of stories){

      let word = stories[0].words[i]

      let input = `<input type="text" name="${word}" placeholder="${word}">`
      $storybox.innerHTML = $storybox.innerHTML + input;
      const $ready = `<span id ="ready>Ready Story</span>`
    }

    $storybox.innerHTML = $ready

  } else {
    console.log("error")
  }
  console.log($buttons.includes("Weather Report"))
})


const stories = [{
    title: 'Mission Statement',
    words: [
      'Adjective',
      'Verb 1',
      'Verb 2',
      'Plural Noun 1',
      'Plural Noun 2',
      'Plural Noun 3'
    ],
    output: function(words) {
      return `<p>Our mission is to <span class="word">${words['Verb 1']}</span> our <span class="word">${words['Plural Noun 2']}</span> with <span class="word">${words.Adjective}</span> <span class="word">${words['Plural Noun 3']}</span> th                             at will <span class="word">${words['Verb 2']}</span> their <span class="word">${words['Plural Noun 1']}</span>.</p>`
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Lunch Room!',
    words: [
      'Animal',
      'Adjective 1',
      'Adjective 2',
      'Vegetable 1',
      'Vegetable 2',
      'Noun',
      'Container'
    ],
    output: function(words) {
      return `<p>Make sure your lunch <span class="word">${words.Container}</span> is filled with <span class="word">${words['Adjective 1']}</span> food. Do not go to the <span class="word">${words['Adjective 2']}</span> food stand across the street from the school. The hamburgers they serve are fried in <span class="word">${words.Noun}</span> and are made of <span class="word">${words.Animal}</span> meat. So take a sandwich made of <span class="word">${words['Vegetable 1']}</span> or <span class="word">${words['Vegetable 2']}</span>, it's much healthier!</p>`
    }
  },

  {
    title: 'Weather Report',
    words: [
      'Adjective 1',
      'Adjective 2',
      'Article of Clothing',
      'Number 1',
      'Number 2',
      'Plural Noun 1',
      'Plural Noun 2'
    ],
    output: function(words) {
      return `<p>Early tomorrow, a <span class="word">${words['Adjective 1']}</span> front will collide with a mass of hot <span class="word">${words['Plural Noun 1']}</span> moving from the north. This means we can expect <span class="word">${words['Adjective 2']}</span> winds and occasional <span class="word">${words['Plural Noun 2']}</span> by late afternoon. Wind velocity will be <span class="word">${words['Number 1']}</span> miles an hour, and the high temperature should be around <span class="word">${words['Number 2']}</span> degrees. So, if you're going out, you had better plan on wearing your<span class="word"> ${words['Article of Clothing']}</span>.</p>`
    }
  }
]
```

```html
<main>

  <h1>Madlibs</h1>

  <h2>
    <h2>
      <div id="storybox"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: You have two `<h2>` with no matching `</h2>`

Comment: Where are you creating any events at all?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the browser automatically adds the closing tags, so its not really needed